# python using asyncio gather with ensure_future

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'have a list of url which i need to fetch concurrently. In order to do that im using asyncio and aiohttp in this way:

```py
async def fetch(session: aiohttp.ClientSession, res):
    async with session.get(f"/foo/bar/{res}") as res:
            return await res.json()

async def get_resources():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(base_url=BASE_URL, headers=HEADERS) as session:
        return await asyncio.gather(*[
            fetch(session, res)
            for res in [resource1, resource2, ...]
        ])
def main():
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        get_resources()
    )
```

this work as i expected, all resources all fire concurrently. but i noticed that i can also use asyncio.ensure_future:

```py
async def get_resources():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(base_url=BASE_URL) as session:
        return await asyncio.gather(*[
            asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(session, res))
            for res in [resource1, resource2, ...]
        ])
```

so im wondering whats the benefit of using another extra call to before call `gather`... in this case `asyncio.ensure_future`.  why not to directly pass a coroutine to `gather` like i did in the first example?

Comment: You shouldn’t use `ensure_future` with this example.

Comment: asyncio.gather converts coroutines to tasks for you, so converting them first makes no difference.  Unless some client is paying you by the number of characters in your source code, there is no benefit whatsoever.